# Install the PostgreSQL driver for Qt 5

Tags: qt, postgresql, ubuntu-14.04

I am running [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr). I have installed Qt from the package  `qt-sdk`. I have also installed the following package which should have installed the PostgreSQL driver:

```
libqt5sql5-psql
```

My Qt version is:

```
Qt Creator 3.0.1 based on Qt 5.2.1
```

When I try to create a Qt db object of type *postgres* like so:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(“QPSQL”);
```

I get a lot of errors like so:

```
/home/bc/projects/qt_test/main.cpp:12: error: stray '\342' in program
     QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(“QPSQL”);
     ^
/home/bc/projects/qt_test/main.cpp:12: error: 'QPSQL' was not declared in this scope
     QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(“QPSQL”);
```

I am obviously not doing something correctly. I don't know what though. Perhaps I am missing a package, or I have misconfigured something.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I highly doubt this has anything to do with any specific database.  It sounds like you copied/pasted code from somewhere and wound up with non-ascii characters in your code.

Comment: You are absolutely right. If you look closely-  the quotes aren't correct. I copy pasted this from the qt documents.

Comment: I fixed it and it works now. You did answer my question, so you might as well make this a proper answer so I can select it as an answer and close the issue.

Comment: Some (crucial) error messages must have been left out. "`“`", at least as posted here, is Unicode code point U+201C ([LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9)). The UTF-8 sequence is 0xE2 0x80 0x9C (hexadecimal), 342 200 234 (octal), so "`error: stray '\342' in program. error: stray '\200' in program. error: stray '\234' in program`" is expected in the error output (three errors for this one character alone).

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Comment: Regular expression `\x{00A0}|\x{200B}|\x{200C}|\x{FEFF}|\x{2013}|\x{2014}|\x{201C}|\x{201D}|\x{2212}|\x{00E4}|\x{FFFC}|\x{FFFD}|\x{2217}|\x{200C}|\x{202B}|\x{202A}|\x{FF1A}|\x{21B5}` can be used to positively identify (and replace) the most common ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a database issue: the compiler is telling you that you have non-ASCII characters in your code that it doesn't recognize:

> error: stray '\342' in program

Take care of those and you should at least get as far as compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Use proper quotes, not the fancy ones from some blogs:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
```